# Regex that search for sentences that exclude one word

Tags: regex, data-cleaning

Ciao guys,

I'm creating a corpus composed with tweets that contain the keyword "**catastrophic**" in XML format. Each tweet are embedded like this:

```
<tweet>"Catastrophic loss" at Tennessee's Zoo Knoxville as 33 reptiles are found dead </tweet>
<tweet>Overcoming Catastrophic Forgetting by Incremental Moment Matching, Lee et al.</tweet
```

After trimming tons of unnecessary data, there are still like 200+ tweets that don't contain the keyword at all. I'd like to delete them, so I tried regex like this, but it just didn't work:

```
<tweet>^.*(?!catastrophic).*$</tweet>
```

Does anybody has any idea?

Comment: the goal is to remove all `<tweet>` tags which don't contain keyword "catastrophic" ? If so, use XML/HTML parser, not regex

Comment: Yes, could you explain a little bit more about it? Thanks!

Comment: what's the programming language?

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what programming language or other toolset you are using.

But a quite simple approach might be to re-write the file (or whatever kind of input it is) using a filter that only writes the entries that do contain catastrophic:

Assuming that it is a file with one line per tweet (just to illustrate the idea):

```
egrep '<tweet>.*catastrophic.*</tweet>' originalFile > newFile
```